# Java Persistence API skip entity

Tags: java, persistence

I am having trouble generating tables from entities. The thing is I am with NetWeaver IDE and dont have an option which entities i would like to make table from and which to skip.

Is there a way to make the generator skip ceratin WHOLE entities? EX: some dummy entities

Comment: Is there any persistence.xml file somewhere in your code? Does the project using maven? Are you using hibernate?

Comment: yes there`s a persistence.xml file. No maven. Probabbly no hibernate aswell

Comment: As far as I know, java persistence checked that persistence.xml to see which class is an entity. So if you don't write that class to persistence.xml, it will not recognize that class ass entity.

Comment: The entities that have to be skipped are in the db, which (db) is going to be moved.

Comment: And then even if I put my classes in the Managed Classes section of the xml when I click generate tables from entities it still tries to generate from all the classes in the package.

Comment: Also it is worth mentioning that the prefixes on those that I want to skip are different...